# Inserting data into element of a generated class

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I've generated a class by xsd.exe tool.

Here is the relevant part of the schema:

```
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="propertyLine">
                        <xs:complexType>
                          <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="value">
                              <xs:complexType mixed="true">
                                <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" />
                              </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                          </xs:sequence>
                        </xs:complexType>
                      </xs:element>
```

After the class generation by xsd I get "propertyLine" array of type:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.3038")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
public partial class MainSubMessageInfoValue {

    private string nameField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string name {
        get {
            return this.nameField;
        }
        set {
            this.nameField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

So I've set data to name attribute by:

```
propertyLine[0].name = "data";
```

But now I want to set data into element **`"value"`** (the one that has the "name" attribute).

What I want to achieve is:

```
<value name="data">Bla Bla Bla</value>
```

How can I do this by code ? How to set "Bla Bla Bla" into "value" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a new property with an `[XmlText]` attribute on it (the name of the property does not matter. It has been a long time since I've dealt with xsd semantics so I'm not sure why it hasn't been generated for you. The best way to add it would be in a separate file (the generated class is partial for this very reason).